# Separation of Business Logic and Data Access Layer and JPA EM Injection

Tags: design-patterns, jpa, ejb-3.0

According to the JEE Core Design Pattern -

> 1. The service layer is there to provide logic to operate on the data sent to and from the DAO and the client.
> 2. DAO is as light as possible and exists solely to provide a connection to the DB, sometimes abstracted so different DB backends
>    can be used

And if the above statements are correct, then why sometimes we see the EntityManager (JPA) being injected into a stateless/ state full EJB. We can take care of the EM in the DAO itself no need to bind it with the Service Layer. I have seen many examples as such but has not yet have the clear reason behind it.

Comment: How will you connect the Service Layer to Data Access Layer?

Comment: @Koray Tugay I will use the interface segregation principle so that the service class shall use the behaviors of an interface to access the implementation DAO and can share required resources.

Comment: I think that is just a design decision and your way maybe useful for bigger projects. To your question, I think the only clear reason is your way may be overhead sometimes..